# How does React differentiate between curly braces used for evaluation and used as JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was looking over my code and noticed this (simplified):

```
onClick={ () => {
    console.log("foo");
} }
```

There are 2 sets of curly braces. The first (outer) pair tells React to evaluate as JS. The second pair is just JS notation for a function. How does React know to not evaluate the contents in the second pair but instead leave it alone?

To clarify, I would think that this code should print foo when the code compiles (without the button being clicked), and then error out because of incorrect function notation (since I think React should run the code inside of the second pair instead of leaving it alone if that makes sense).

Comment: This pattern is only used in JSX.  The outer curly braces are telling React that between these is javascript.  `() =>` creates a callback which is why it doesn't print out on the initial render.  It's listening for the click before it will do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important part of this that you are missing is the `() =>`.

This tells the browser that what follows is an anonymous function declaration. This is called the "fat arrow" syntax, or just "arrow functions"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Because the part inside the outer pair of `{}` is a function definition (because it starts with `() =>`) The console.log statement will not be run until something else *calls* that function.

In your example, the function will be called when user clicks on the  html element that is ultimately rendered by react.

Comment: So you are saying that React recognizes the () => , so it doesn't try to evaluate what comes next? That makes a lot of sense, so I will upvote.

Comment: Yes though, in the end it's the browser, not react that is actually deciding not to run that code right away. React, after-all compiles to plain javascript. And the concept of an anonymous function, and the arrow function are parts of javascript.

Answer (score 1):

This code should print foo when a user clicked to the button. The "first" curly braces tell React that is JS code. In case it's event handler: onClick, onChange, etc - it should be a function that will be called on the event.

So, you bundled this arrow function to the onClick event.